# Why is ホームシック a noun, not a な-adjective?

Tags: loanwords, na-adjectives, nouns

In class, I was told that ホームシック is a noun, not a な-adjective.

```
ホームシックの時、何をしますか。
```

By contrast, the closest English word to "ホームシック", which is "homesick", is an adjective.

Why is ホームシック a noun? Is it describing a disease (if you had to use English, you might say "homesickness"), rather than the state of having the disease?

Comment: @Downvoter: What is wrong with my question? Is there an invalid assumption in it?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it's worth noting that Japanese has no 形容詞 or 形容動詞(な-adjective) which directly corresponds to the English adjective *sick*. (although you can say 「彼の具合【ぐあい】が悪【わる】い
」, if you don't mind replacing the subject)

We can say 「彼 は [病名] だ」、「[病名] の 人」、「 [病名] に なる」、where [病名] can be 癌 (cancer), 肺炎 (pneumonia), 糖尿病 (diabetes), 骨粗鬆症 (osteoporosis), or 病気 (disease) in general. And they are all nouns. We usually cannot say 「 [病名] な 人」, so 「癌な人」 or 「糖尿病な人」 is wrong.

I think that's why we often treat the loanword ホームシック also as a noun. Words such as *lovesick* or *airsick* have no corresponding adjectives either in Japanese; instead we have nouns 恋煩【こいわずら】い (love sickness) or 飛行機酔【ひこうきよ】い (air sickness).

That said, I think this rule is somewhat loosened if certain 外来語 diseases are concerned. In fact, **both 「ホームシックな時」 and 「メタボな人」 sound as natural as 「ホームシックの時」 and 「メタボの人」 to me**. Japanese tend to create many な-adjectives from English adjectives, as in スマートな, リスキーな, etc. They can even create な-adjectives from English nouns, such as [ワンパターンな](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%AF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3),　ハイリスクな. I see no reason why *homesick* cannot act as a な-adjective as well as a noun.

Lastly, some people may argue that Japanese young people use "病気な人", or more commonly, "ビョーキな人". Such use of 病気 is a slang and [has a special meaning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%97%85%E6%B0%97) (abnormal, crazy, mad). Use "病気の人" for someone with a real medical disorder.

Answer (score 6):

ホームシック is understood as describing the state of being homesick. You can parallel it with 病気 (as in ホームシックになる vs. 病気になる, ホームシックの時 vs. 病気の時), but being perceived as a noun doesn't imply that it is describing a disease.

メタボ (derived from メタボリックシンドローム{metabolic syndrome}) appears to be used both as noun and as *na*-adjective, e.g. メタボの人 vs. メタボな人.

Moreover, I think that *na*-adjectives characterize something as having permanently a certain property, whereas characterizing with の implies a more temporary property.

> メタボの人 sounds more like someone who *at the moment* suffers from metabolic disorder.
>
> メタボな人 sounds more like someone who "has" metabolic syndrome.

Since ホームシック is definitely temporary, ホームシックの sounds more natural. ホームシックな人 sounds a little like an oxymoron.