# Why do you put 名詞 plus の before ようだ, but you put 名詞 plus な before わけだ?

Tags: grammar, particles

I looked up the dictionary, and found "よう" and "わけ" are both grammatical nouns (形式体言). But why is the 接続 different?

Moreover, I found many sentence patterns have their own rules. Are there any universal rules which determine which form you should conjugate into?

Comment: Iirc のわけ is also correct, but I'm also interested to why なわけ is used with nouns

Comment: なようだ is possible as well. のわけだ is rare.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can「病気【びょうき】」be used as a 形容動詞【けいようどうし】 (na-adjective)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70486/can-%e7%97%85%e6%b0%97-%e3%81%b3%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8d-be-used-as-a-%e5%bd%a2%e5%ae%b9%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e-%e3%81%91%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%97-na-adjective)

Answer (score 2):

This の is a particle joining two nouns and な is the describing form of the copula. As such, it is joining a sentence (ending in a noun or keiyōdōshi) with a noun. So *in theory*, の takes only the noun, but な the entire sentence.

This difference between わけ and よう can be explained with the different meanings: わけ means something like "conclusion", as such, it only makes sense with a sentence modifying it. 魚のわけ "the conclusion of the fish" makes no sense, or at least not the one we want. It only makes sense with a sentence: それは魚なわけだ "the conclusion that it is a fish" or "that means it's a fish". When one has to translate よう with a noun, maybe "lookalike" would match. 魚のよう "lookalike of a fish" or "like a fish" with just the noun already makes sense. When used in a sentence like それは魚のようだ "that is like a fish" can also be parsed as それは[魚のよう]だ, instead of "(それは魚)のようだ".

But なよう is also possible, just not so frequent.

Answer (score -1):

It's because の emphasizes possession

AがBなわけだ → AがBであるわけだ

AがBのようだ → AがBの様子をしている

But の can also function as the copula, and ～であるよう can work, so both are viable. The meaning is just not as strong or obvious so the usage tends toward this.

Comment: The sense of の is [definitely broader than simply "possession" as an English speaker would understand it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/).